# One dataset for many wallets... how?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, client, rescan

It takes a while to download and process the transaction log.
Doing that for dozens of wallets would be a big waste.
I want to run just one client full time as a log processor.
Then for each wallet, symlink the log processor's data
files into each wallet's homedir.
Even if I can't tell each client to NOT pull down new
logs and process them, I can still copy the processor's ones
in as needed and then start the client.

So what files in the homedir are wallet specific, wallet signed,
or in ANY way linked to your wallet and keys/ids, etc?

And what files are completely safe/anonymous to redistribute, crossplant,
etc.

How do I separate the identity files from the network data files?

What files are, and do, exactly what?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Only the `wallet.dat` file is specific to the wallet. You can stop the client, swap out the `wallet.dat` file for a different wallet, and then launch the client again. You may need to start the client with the `-rescan` option -- the client will do the right thing automatically in most cases, but there are a few corner cases it mishandles without `-rescan`.